# Get Distinct by Property based on the spelling distance

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, extension-methods

i have this collection and i want to sort it based on rating then remove the duplicate name based on the nearest spelling distance using Levenshtein Algorithm..

here's my code so far

and my expected result is

```
 /* 
  * Expected result:
  * 
  * Jjamppong v2
  * Maggi
  * Quick Chow
  * 
  */
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Item> _items = new List<Item>();

            _items.Add(new Item() { ItemID = 1, Name = "Jjamppong", Rating = 4 });
            _items.Add(new Item() { ItemID = 2, Name = "Jjamppong v2", Rating = 6 });
            _items.Add(new Item() { ItemID = 3, Name = "Jjamppong v3", Rating = 3 });
            _items.Add(new Item() { ItemID = 4, Name = "Jjamppong v4", Rating = 2 });
            _items.Add(new Item() { ItemID = 5, Name = "Maggi", Rating = 8 });
            _items.Add(new Item() { ItemID = 6, Name = "Quick Chow", Rating = 1 });
            _items.Add(new Item() { ItemID = 7, Name = "Maggi v2", Rating = 5 });


            _items.OrderByDescending(i => i.Rating)
                .Distinct(new DistinctByNameNearComparer<Item>())
                .Select(i => i)
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(i =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(i.Name);
                });

            Console.ReadKey();


            /* 
             * Expected result:
             * 
             * Jjamppong v2
             * Maggi
             * Quick Chow
             * 
             */
        }
    }

    class Item
    {
        public int ItemID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Rating { get; set; }
    }

    class DistinctByNameNearComparer : IEqualityComparer<Item>
    {

        public bool Equals(Item x, Item y)
        {
            int _distance = LevenshteinDistance.Compute(x.Name, y.Name);
            int _maxLen = Math.Max(x.Name.Length, y.Name.Length);

            return (_distance > (_maxLen - 5));
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Item obj)
        {
            return obj.GetHashCode();
        }
    }

    class LevenshteinDistance
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Compute the distance between two strings.
        /// </summary>
        public static int Compute(string s, string t)
        {
            int n = s.Length;
            int m = t.Length;
            int[,] d = new int[n + 1, m + 1];

            // Step 1
            if (n == 0)
            {
                return m;
            }

            if (m == 0)
            {
                return n;
            }

            // Step 2
            for (int i = 0; i <= n; d[i, 0] = i++)
            {
            }

            for (int j = 0; j <= m; d[0, j] = j++)
            {
            }

            // Step 3
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {
                //Step 4
                for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++)
                {
                    // Step 5
                    int cost = (t[j - 1] == s[i - 1]) ? 0 : 1;

                    // Step 6
                    d[i, j] = Math.Min(
                        Math.Min(d[i - 1, j] + 1, d[i, j - 1] + 1),
                        d[i - 1, j - 1] + cost);
                }
            }
            // Step 7
            return d[n, m];
        }
    }
}
```

i got an error here

```
_items.OrderByDescending(i => i.Rating)
                    .Distinct(new DistinctByNameNearComparer<Item>())
                    .Select(i => i)
                    .ToList()
                    .ForEach(i =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(i.Name);
                    });
```

any help would be appreciated.

**ANSWER:**

```
class DistinctByNameNearComparer : IEqualityComparer<Item>
    {

        public bool Equals(Item x, Item y)
        {
            int _distance = LevenshteinDistance.Compute(x.Name, y.Name);
            int _maxLen = Math.Max(x.Name.Length, y.Name.Length);
            bool _comp = _distance < 4;

            return _comp;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Item obj)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: so what error are you getting?

Comment: **.Distinct(new DistinctByNameNearComparer<Item>())** i think this is not the way how  to implement a defined class inherited from IEqualityComparer<Item> because i got an error there.. i just cant make it to work that's why i hit here.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you're receiving [Compiler Error CS0308](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfhfe070%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), saying

> The non-generic type-or-method 'identifier' cannot be used with type
>   arguments.
>
> The method or type is not generic, but it was used with type
>   arguments. To avoid this error, remove the angled brackets and type
>   arguments, or redeclare the method or type as a generic method or
>   type.

So the correct linq would be:

```
_items.OrderByDescending(i => i.Rating)
    .Distinct(new DistinctByNameNearComparer())
    .Select(i => i)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(i =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i.Name);
    });
```

while you specify

```
.Distinct(new DistinctByNameNearComparer<Item>())
```

The error is that `DistinctByNameNearComparer` is not generic, so you cannot specify a type parameter for it. Compiler infers from `_items.OrderByDescending(i => i.Rating)` that the argument for `Distinct` should be of type `IEqualityComparer<Item>` and you're expected to specify it. However your `DistinctByNameNearComparer` is declared as

```
class DistinctByNameNearComparer : IEqualityComparer<Item>
```

that is, it really is `IEqualityComparer<Item>`. The only thing you need to do is to write

```
.Distinct(new DistinctByNameNearComparer())
```

Comment: it compiles but returns result that is not what i expected Maggi, Jjamppong v2, Maggi v2, Jjamppong, Jjamppong v3, Jjamppong v4, Quick Chow

Comment: it just order the items by rating in descending order but didn't do the distinct part

Comment: @VincentDagpin for the items to be concerned equal the `GetHashCode` method should return one value for equal items, while your implementation does not.

Comment: @VincentDagpin if you try to debug this code, you'll see that DistinctByNameNearComparer.Equals method does not get called even once. The reason is that it will get called only for objects with equal hash

Comment: can i make it to the point that the HashCode will not matter? like, it will go to the .Equal() without checking the hashcode?

Comment: @VincentDagpin Well, you may make them all return one and the same value, however, the result seems still to be far from what you're expecting

Comment: @VincentDagpin say, `public int GetHashCode(Item obj) { return 0; }`

Comment: i changed the .Equal() method a little bit. :)